# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setAttribute: Non-serializable attribute with name

Tags: java, spring-mvc, serialization

I am new to Spring MVC, trying to write the web based application ...getting following error.....

```
 org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setAttribute:
```

Non-serializable attribute with name 
InventoryMgmtSpring.web.PriceIncreaseFormController.FORM.priceIncrease
root cause

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: setAttribute: Non-serializable attribute with name InventoryMgmtSpring.web.PriceIncreaseFormController.FORM.priceIncrease
```

code snippet from app-servelet.xml

```
  <bean name="/priceincrease.htm"   class="InventoryMgmtSpring.web.PriceIncreaseFormController">
    <property name="sessionForm" value="true"/>
    <property name="commandName" value="priceIncrease"/>
    <property name="commandClass" value="InventoryMgmtSpring.service.PriceIncrease"/>
    <property name="validator">
        <bean class="InventoryMgmtSpring.service.PriceIncreaseValidator"/>
    </property>
    <property name="formView" value="priceincrease.htm"/>
    <property name="successView" value="hello.htm"/>
    <property name="productManager" ref="productManager"/>
</bean>
```

### code from PriceIncreaseFormController -----

```
 public class PriceIncreaseFormController extends SimpleFormController {

/** Logger for this class and subclasses */
protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass()); 
private ProductManager productManager; 

public ModelAndView onSubmit(Object command) throws ServletException { 
    int increase = ((PriceIncrease) command).getPercentage();
    logger.info("Increasing prices by " + increase + "%."); 
    productManager.increasePrice(increase); 
    logger.info("returning from PriceIncreaseForm view to " + getSuccessView()); 
    return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(getSuccessView()));
} 

protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
    PriceIncrease priceIncrease = new PriceIncrease();
    priceIncrease.setPercentage(20);
    return priceIncrease;
} 
public void setProductManager(ProductManager productManager) {
    this.productManager = productManager;
} 
public ProductManager getProductManager() {
    return productManager;
    } 
    }
```

code snippet from PriceIncrease
=------------------------------

```
 public class PriceIncrease {

/** Logger for this class and subclasses */

protected  final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
private int percentage ;
public void setPercentage(int i)
{
    this.percentage=i;
    logger.info("Percentage set to" + i);
}
public int getPercentage()
{
    return percentage;
  }
 }
```

Comment: not working yet. any  modification required in class???

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone. I found out the mistakes...

1) class PriceIncrease  implementes Serializable.

2)  the value has to be changed as "priceincrease" rather than "priceincrease.htm"

Code is working fine. Thanks again for your help

Comment: implements Serializable was the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would avoid having a Logger in PriceIncrease and treat the PriceIncrease more like a POJO. It is hard to determine what exactly might the root cause of your problem, but I believe that the problem might be when you are trying to serialize the logger. Try removing the logger or add the keyword transient before the log variable.

I hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you the `priceIncrease` property of the `FORM` property of `PriceIncreaseFormController` is of a type that does not implement `java.io.Serializable`. I don't see any `FORM` property in the code you posted so either the posted code has been modified or the property is higher in the inheritance tree (`SimpleFormController`).